# How to automate db deployments in visual studio 2010?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to put together an automated deployment strategy for my company's .NET application. We are using TFS/VS 2010, along with IIS for application hosting and msbuild for continuous integration & deployment. The application consists primarily of two components:
* A webapp
* A database

Our branching strategy, for the moment, is single-stream. That is, we have one big 'ol trunk, and for now we can assume that it will remain that way.

We've figured out how to get msbuild to deploy the webapp to IIS, so that's cool. Now I'm trying to figure out the best strategy for handling deployment of the database component. Right now, database deployment is entirely manual: our db architect builds the db on his machine periodically, examines the auto-generated migration script, and then manually writes pre/post deployment scripts. Then, he runs the whole deployment and sends an email to everyone.

This is not an ideal solution: the automated nightly webapp deployment works great, except when the dba fails to coordinate his manual db deployment work. This results in a lot of headaches for all parties. Thus, I'm trying to figure out how feasible an auto-deployment of the db will be.

I understand how to make msbuild deploy a database. However, the bigger problem seems to be properly managing pre/post deployment scripts.

With all this in mind, can anyone point me to best practices in this kind of a situation? I've done a lot of config mgmt in the past, but am new to managing a project with a database component.

Comment: I don't know, if the new database-projects in VS 2012 might be an option for you. I've only tested it with SQLS. The point is, that it includes Schema Compare which leads to files which can be part of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

we use the Visual Tool VSDBCMD to compare 2 databases and generating update sql scripts

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx

Comment: I believe that's the program baked into VSTS2010, right? We've done dbproject builds, and schema migration script is generated by VSDBCMD, I think.